# Filter li elements in ul and preserve path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to expand my filtering function for li elements in ul.
My ul structure looks like this:

```html
    <ul>
        <li class="root"><span class="text">Root1</span>
            <ul>
                <li class="list"><span class="text">li1.1</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="root"><span class="text">Root2</span>
            <ul style="display: block;">
                <li class="root"><span class="text">Root2.1</span>
                    <ul style="display: block;"></ul>
                </li>
                <li class="root"><span class="text">Root2.2</span>
                    <ul style="display: block;">
                        <li class="list"><span class="text">li2.2.1</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="root"><span class="text">Root2.3</span>
                    <ul style="display: block;">
                        <li class="list"><span class="text">li2.3.1</span></li>
                        <li class="list"><span class="text">li2.3.2</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="root"><span class="text">Root3</span>
            <ul>
                <li class="list"><span class="text">li3.1</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="root"><span class="text">Root4</span>
            <ul>
                <li class="list"><span class="text">li4.1</span></li>
                <li class="list"><span class="text">li4.2</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Currently I have filter function that filters based on query among .list elements. Now I'm trying to implement it in a way, that while filtering list (still only .list elements), there would be structure history.

For example: searching for "li2.3.2" would return:

```html
    <ul>
        <li class="root"><span class="text">Root2</span>
            <ul style="display: block;">
                <li class="root"><span class="text">Root2.3</span>
                    <ul style="display: block;">
                        <li class="list"><span class="text">li2.3.2</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

EDIT: For clarification and since I failed to mention that in original post...I'm trying to filter by users input (partial matching counts).
My current method works by taking users input in text input box, taking all .list elements in ul and comparing for each element if span.text contains searching text.

Comment: You will need to write the code that you have implemented so far

Answer (score 0):

you should give `class` every floor,and use CSS filter `:parent` and `:nth-chiled` find what you want

Answer (score 0):

@pc9529, yes it is possible. but here you want o display only parent li node html. So give different class to the li which is belonging from your parent UL. Look at the given solution,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
       if($(this).hasClass("root1"))
       {
        
            alert($('<div>').append($(this).clone()).html());
       }
       else{
          alert($('<div>').append($(this).closest(".root1").clone()).html());
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li class="root1"><span class="text">Root1</span>
            <ul>
                <li class="list"><span class="text">li1.1</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="root1"><span class="text">Root2</span>
            <ul style="display: block;">
                <li class="root"><span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span><i class="fa root-checkbox fa-square-o"></i><span class="text">Root2.1</span>
                    <ul style="display: block;"></ul>
                </li>
                <li class="root"><span class="text">Root2.2</span>
                    <ul style="display: block;">
                        <li class="list"><span class="text">li2.2.1</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="root"><span class="text">Root2.3</span>
                    <ul style="display: block;">
                        <li class="list"><span class="text">li2.3.1</span></li>
                        <li class="list"><span class="text">li2.3.2</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="root1"><span class="text">Root3</span>
            <ul>
                <li class="list"><span class="text">li3.1</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="root1"><span class="text">Root4</span>
            <ul>
                <li class="list"><span class="text">li4.1</span></li>
                <li class="list"><span class="text">li4.2</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I'm sorry since I failed to mention that in original post. I'm doing this by searching with users input in 'keyup' function, so partial matching is valid.

Comment: so you have textbox for search and through it you want to filter tree?

Comment: Yes. Filter applies only to .text elements, but main problem is avoiding all other .list and .root elements in filtered data.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnvu56fh/23/)

The JQuery finds your item by text, then find all parents that contain the ".root" class, and finally gets the last parent i.e. the root ul element of the hierarchy.

```
$('.list:contains("li2.3.2")').parents('.root').last().html()
```

Comment: My goal is not to show other .root elements. For example searching for "li2.3.2" all elements in Root2 although Root2.1 and Root2.2 don't have matching element.